# nodejs logging to multiple files

Tags: node.js

Reading [How to log - the 12 factor application way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968560/how-to-log-the-12-factor-application-way) it states to use this command :

```
node app.js 2> app.err 1> app.out
```

I understand the `>` operator sends the output of command to file.

So I could also use `node app.js output.log`.

For command `node app.js 2> app.err 1> app.out` what is the mechanism that determines if app.err or app.out is logged to. Is it by the logging level within in the app ? What extra config is required to send logging data to app.err & app.out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected behavior is that the output sent to `stderr` will be redirected to `app.err`, while output sent to `stdout` will go into `app.out`. For example this script:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var transports = [
    new winston.transports.Console({
        level: 'debug',
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: false,
        timestamp: () => (new Date()).toLocaleString(),
        colorize: false
    })
];

var logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: transports,
    exitOnError: false
});

logger.error('goes to stderr');
logger.info('goes to stdout');
```

would write `goes to stderr` to `app.err`, while `goes to stdout` would appear in `app.out`. This default behavior can be however overridden with the [`stderrLevels`](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#console-transport) property using which one can specify which debug levels go to `stderr`.

Alternatively, using `console`, the behavior is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html) - by default, `console.error` goes to `stderr` (i.e., `app.err` in your setup) while `console.log` would output to `stdout` (`app.out`).

Comment: thanks >2 and >1 is command line config for piping to multiple files? , is is not related to node?

Comment: @blue-sky that's a general thing - see for example [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)